# How can I save an Excel file as a PDF while maintaining frozen Frames?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pdf, adobe-acrobat

I'm using Excel 2013. I have a spreadsheet where the first row is "frozen". So when I scroll up and down that first row stays put. It contains the titles for each row. When I save the file as a PDF, the ability to freeze the first row goes away. I know its possible because I've done it before. But I can't for the life of me do it again. Please help.

EDIT: Here is an [example](http://sdrv.ms/11Q3Z14)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Repeat title rows at the top of each page as suggested by Travis. Now every page has the same header.

In Acrobat Reader, select View > Page Display > Single Page View

At the same time, scrolling is de-selected. So, the visible part of the page never changes. While scrolling through pages, which all have the same header, it appears as if the header is frozen and the content below the header scrolls. But that's an optical illusion. If you look closely, you'll see that the screen content changes one page at a time, not one row at a time, so it's paging rather than scrolling. With the header in a fixed position, the illusion is almost perfect.

It is not an Excel setting, but an Adobe Reader setting. I don't know if this setting can be manipulated from Excel, or if it requires a PDF creator like Acrobat.

Comment: Your right Teylyn, thank you. The setting in Acrobat was what I was missing.

Comment: Thanks for this teylyn!  I'll know it is possible from now on!

Answer (score 2):

Page Layout, Print Titles.  Rows to repeat at top.

Comment: That does add the title to the top of each page. But I'm looking for the same functionality that Excel gives by freezing the top row. Then when scroll up and down the first row will always be on screen.

Comment: Maybe you can *print* the file to PDF using something like pdf995 http://www.pdf995.com/ or similar tools?

Comment: Tried that with no success.

Comment: That cannot be done with PDFs. A PDF shows the content as it would appear on printed paper. PDF is not a spreadsheet.

Comment: It can be done. I have PDF files to prove it.

Comment: I found some articles elsewhere that shows exactly what you are talking about.  I would say it is probably an Adobe Pro header function, not something that is in the free reader.

Comment: I've never had Acrobat Pro. I'm sure I did it with just Excel. I just can't remember how I did it.

Comment: Got me.  Anxious to know now

Answer (score 0):

Go to the page layout tab at the top, select the "Print Titles" pull down menu and a page setup box will pop up.  In the "Rows to Repeat" at the top bar, click on the icon on the right, then click on the top row in your excel file.

Answer (score 0):

"Go to the page layout tab at the top, select the "Print Titles" pull down menu and a page setup box will pop up. In the "Rows to Repeat" at the top bar, click on the icon on the right, then click on the top row in your excel file."

I didn't think this would work, as you seem to be preparing the page for printing only. But it does work! After setting up repeat Rows to Repeat, simply save as PDF.

Comment: Hi Alan, thanks for chiming in, but you're not really providing a new answer. Rather, you're confirming an existing answer with a useful insight. You may want to convert your answer to a comment on the answer you're replying to. Cheers!